# How can I (algebraically) prove that the relation $x^3+y^3-12xy=0$ has two tangents at the origin?

Tags: analytic-geometry

How can I (algebraically) prove that the relation $x^3+y^3-12xy=0$ has two tangents at the origin?

Comment: Isn't differentiation an analytic (instead of algebraic) technique? Algebraically tangents to a polynomial equation should be defined by root multiplicities

Comment: Your should try to rephrase your question. It is very hard to understand your reasoning.

Comment: @Martin Improve formatting and correct your computations

Comment: If you accept the answer below, please click the "accept button".

Comment: What happened to the sum rule and the product rule? Do you understand the hypotheses for implicit differentiation to be valid?

Comment: @Martin Please, at least, rectify your derivative computation. It does not look good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plane algebraic curve is defined by a polynomial in two variables $f(x, y)$, where $f(x, y) = 0$.

To show that something happens at the origin, we first need to verify that the origin is on the curve. The origin is $(x, y) = (0, 0)$, so we plug $x = y = 0$ into $f$. Do we get 0? Good. The origin $(0, 0)$ is on $C$.

The next thing to do is determine if the curve is singular at $(0, 0)$. Most points on most curves are smooth, and there is a single tangent at smooth points. At singular points, there could be all kinds of different behaviors.

The test for smoothness is simple: compute the gradient of $f$. The gradient is just the vector $\nabla f = (\partial f / \partial x, \partial f / \partial y)$, evaluated at the point of interest. If the gradient is nonzero, there is a tangent: the line perpendicular to the gradient. If the gradient vanishes, we have a singularity.

In our case, $\nabla f = (3x^2 - 12y, 3y^2 - 12x)$, and indeed $\nabla f = (0, 0)$ at $(0, 0)$. So we already know that $C$ is singular at $(0, 0)$, but we still need to determine the type of singularity. Are there two tangents there? None? Many?

These are some of the ways a (real) plane algebraic curve can be singular at the origin:

[image]
(The top left example is actually the present curve).

To find the different tangents, we can write $x=at$ and $y=bt$. This describes a straight line through the origin as $t$ varies, and it's a bit better than writing $y=ax$ because then we would miss the vertical line.

Putting $(x,y)=(at,bt)$ in the equation we get

$(at)^3+(bt)^3-12(at)(bt)=0$

or

$t^2(a^3t+b^3t-12ab)=0$

First of all, no matter what $a$ and $b$ are (i.e. no matter what line we are thinking of), we see that $t=0$ is a double root of this equation, which means that every straight line through the origin meets our curve twice at the origin.

But, when $a=0$ or $b=0$ (but not both), the term $-12ab$ disappears and we get $t^3(a^3+b^3)=0$, and now $t=0$ is a triple root. That means that the lines $(x=t,y=0)$ and $(x=0,y=t)$ meet our curve not twice (as usual) but three times – and that extra multiplicity is, geometrically, a tangency. Instead of slicing right through, the line gently hugs the curve, touching it one extra time.
[image]
[image]

It's beautiful to see how an algebraic property (the degree $k$ of the factor $t^k$) faithfully captures the geometry.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple technique using the so-called **Newton's polygon** associated with the given polynomial in two variables :

The idea is first to associate the point $(n,p) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ to each monomial $ax^ny^p$ (coefficient $a$ isn't taken into account). For example, to the polynomial equation $13x^3y^2-5x^2y^2+5xy+7x=0$, the following points will be associated $(3,2), \ (2,2), \ (1,1), \ (1,0)$. In a second step, the convex hull is considered, and, for our purpose (being able to have all branches passing through the origin) considering only the *lower part of the convex envelope* as in the following example borrowed to [this site](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/NewtonPolygonAndBranchingOfAlgebraicCurves/). We see the behavior of the curve given by equation $-x^4+x^2y^3+\cdots = 0$ **in the vicinity of the origin**. On the right graphic, one sees two branches : one of them looks parabolic (think to $y=ax^2$), the other one looks "pinched", reminding, with a little habit, a local behavior of the form  $y=ax^{p/q}$ (fractional exponent).

[image]

Now, the Newton polygonal is going to confirm our intuition.

Indee, the lower part of the convex hull is constituted by two line segments :

- The first one joining $(0,4)$ to $(2,1)$ with slope $\color{red}{2/3}$ when looking the line at $90°$.
- The second one joining $(2,1)$ to $(4,0)$ with slope $\color{red}{2}$.

These 2 slope values give the exponents we are looking for :

$$y=x^{\color{red}{2/3}} \ \text{in the first case and } \ y=x^{\color{red}{2}} \ \text{in the second case}$$

Moreover, there are exactly two different branches passing through the origin, therefore two tangents.

Up to you : check that it works on *your* polynomial !

I will not do any theory justifying this technique. You will find it, together with other uses of Newton's polygon for example on this site in certain questions/answers like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1678839/305862).

Comment: An interesting [article](https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Polya/07468342.di020774.02p0260v.pdf).

Comment: Great explanation thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

Your derivative computation is wrong. Also, you cannot use these formulas here, as at the origin, there are multiple tangents. Given a polynomial function $f(x,y)$, one can write it as a sum of forms, say $f(x,y)=f_0+f_1+\cdots+f_m$, where $m$ is the total degree of $f$ and $f_i's$ are either zero or is a form in $x,y$ having total degree $i$, for each $0\le i\le m$. The tangent(s) at the origin will be given by setting $f_k=0$ and factorizing it into linear forms (at least over $\mathbb{C}$), where $k$ is the least index $i$ such that $f_i$ is not zero. In your case, $f_k=-12xy$ and so the tangents at the origin are $x=0,y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It does look like $x y = 0$ in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Let's try to show that the function factorizes as a product in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$. Apply a linear change of coordinates

$$(x,y) = (p+q, p-q)$$ and get

$$p^2 - q^2 - \frac{p^3}{6} - \frac{p q^2}{2}=0$$

or

$$p^2(1 -\frac{p}{6}) = q^2( 1 + \frac{p}{2})$$

that is

$$q = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{p}{6}}{1 + \frac{p}{2}}}\cdot p$$

Now we see that around $(0,0)$ ( for $|p|$ small) the curve is the union of the graphs of two functions.

---

Note: if we had a curve of the form

$$F(p,q) = p^2 - q^2 + \textrm{ higher order terms} = 0$$ then each of the higher order terms is divisible by $p^2$ or $q^2$ ( or both), so we can group as

$$p^2 ( 1 + \textrm{h.o.t}) - q^2( 1 + \textrm{h.o.t}) = 0$$
or
$$p_1^2 - q_1^2 =0$$
where
$$p_1 = p \sqrt{ 1 + \textrm{h.o.t}} \\
q_1 = q \sqrt{1 + \textrm{h.o.t}}$$

Now $(p_1, q_1)$ is a new system of coordinates around $(0,0)$, so the curve around $(0,0)$ is the union of two curves $q_1 = \pm p_1$.

This is a particular case of [Morse lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse_lemma).

$\bf{Added:}$ We can try some ad-hoc methods on curves of the form

$$F(x,y) = x^3 - y^3 + \textrm{h.o.t}=0$$

around $(0,0)$. Now the higher order terms are of degree $\ge 0$, so they either are divisible by $x^3$ or $y^3$, or are $ c x^2 y^2$. Multiply $F$ by $1-c x^2 y^2$ to get an equivalent equation around $(0,0)$ that now has all terms divisible by $x^3$ or $y^3$

$$x^3(1+ \textrm{h.o.t}) - y^3( 1+ \textrm{h.o.t.})= 0$$

or
$$x_1^3 - y_1^3= 0$$

The factor $x_1^2 + x_1 y_1 + y_1^2 = 0$ gives only $(0,0)$, so the real curves appears to be the smooth $x_1 - y_1 = 0$.